# Angular href link does not open in IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, hyperlink

I have a shared-code application in Android and IOS and the link will open in Android but won't on an IOS device. Is there any difference between them in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to open in Safari and it worked?

Comment: I'm trying in Google Chrome, I will try in Safari as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using Angular routing ?

```
this.router.navigate(["/"])
```

or if its external routing try

```
window.open(url)
```

OR

```
this.router.navigate(['/']).then(() => {
    window.open(url);
});
```

Comment: It's an external html link which redirects to a different website in a new tab, is it possible to use router.navigate in this context?

Comment: Unfortunetly no